# How to check if email is already in use in asp.net and making sure email is available before allowing the user to register?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I need to check an SQL Server database (not asp.net membership) to see if an email is already in use before allowing the user to register.

I have tried using the information in [this website](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-check-username-availability.html?showComment=1321715913515#c2089502784717794334) but it does not seem to work.

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: What isn't working with the example? are you getting any errors?

Comment: @53AN I am not getting errors, the text that says "Username available or not available" is not showing up. Plus I can still register the same email again, it should not allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
    protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text))
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName like " + txtUsername.Text.Trim(), con);//I changed
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "NotAvailable.jpg";
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
            }
            else
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "Icon_Available.gif";
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
            }
            con.Close();//I added
        }
        else
        {
            checkusername.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```